# SwiftyJSON - Returning json array from func

Tags: json, swift, function, parsing, return

I am working on my local json api and it works quite fine with receiving and parsing data using swiftyjson and alamofire, but when it comes to return these data, I have some troubles:

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

...

func getApi() -> Array<JSON> {

    let user = "user"
    let password = "password"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost/api/")
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
        .responseString { (req, res, body, error) in

            if let data = (body)!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

                let json = JSON(data: data)

                println(json) // works fine

                return json // does not work   
            }
    }
}
```

So it prints "JSON is not convertible to Void"...

Anybody knows how to deal with this?

You think i am doing right using alamofire for a "http-basic-authentification" ?

Greetings and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If your api returns a JSON object, alamofire provides a .responseJSON, and swiftyJSON can wrap that response.

Also don't forget that this request is asynchronous, so you probably need to get these results in a completion handler, something like this:

```
func getApi(completionHandler: (jsonResponse: JSON) -> () {
    let user = "user"
    let password = "password"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost/api/")
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
        .responseJSON { (req, res, JSON, error) in

                println(json) // works fine

                completionHandler(json)
            }
    }
}
```

Call the method like so:

```
getAPI(completionHandler: { (response: JSON) -> () in
  // do something with your response. If the JSON contains an array you can iterate through it here.
}
```

Next good thing will be to check the "Response Serialization" section on Alamofire doc.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to return an object of type JSON inside a block that has no return type (Void).

Answer (score 1):

according to your variable names, you should set

```
res = json
```

or

```
res.setResponse(json)
```

or smt like that. Can't check now because I'm far away from my mac at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns an array of JSON: `[JSON]`.

You are trying to return a single `JSON` type object.

Change your return statement to return an array:

```
return [json] // should work
```

### EDIT: I misread the code when I posted my answer. You are calling an async method, Alamofire.request. That method returns immediately, but the data isn't actually loaded until sometime later. Your current design won't work.

@Gwendle's answer is the right one. You need to refactor your method to take a completion block and put the response handling in that completion block.

Comment: The author is attempting to return an object of type JSON inside the Alamofire block which has no return type, hence the Void error.